# Unit Test Error creating bean with name "amqAdmin" while testing spring integration TCP component

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I'm writing a sidecar micro service that talks TCP to a legacy app and uses rabbitMQ on the other side.  I'm just getting started and writing tests as I go along to better understand how everything works as I'm new to Spring.  My app builds, deploys, and runs fine.

However,  writing clean tests has been a bit more complicated.  I have been patterning my code off the spring-integration tcp basic examples.  I started with having a mock TCPServer to test my code defined outside my test class.  But the mock TCPServer kept being built for every test class.  So I moved it into the TCPGatewayTest class similar to the example I [found](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/tcp-client-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/tcpclientserver/TcpClientServerAnnotationDemoTest.java).

This led to some missing bean issues which led me to add a @ContextConfiguration annotation which has gotten me further.  But now I have other missing beans.  I'm sure I'm messing up my ApplicationContext with @ContextConfiguration.  Is there a better way of doing this with a different annotation or doing it slightly different?  I'm not going the xml route and would like to steer clear of it if possible.

The familiar no qualifying bean error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

---

My Test Class is the following

```
package org.inc.imo;

@ComponentScan("org.inc")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TCPGatewayTest.TCPServerMock.class, 
                                 org.inc.imo.Configuration.TCPConfig.class, 
                                 org.inc.imo.Configuration.RabbitConfig.class })
@TestPropertySource(locations= "classpath:test.properties")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TCPGatewayTest {

    @Autowired
    private TCPGateway gateway;

    @Autowired
    AbstractServerConnectionFactory crLfServer;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        TestingUtilities.waitListening(this.crLfServer, 10000L);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConnectionToMockServer() {
        String result = gateway.send("Hello World");

        assertEquals("HELLO WORLD", result);
    }

    @Configuration
    @MessageEndpoint
    public static class TCPServerMock {

        @Value("${imo.port}")
        private int port;

        @Bean()
        public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverCF() {
            return new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(this.port);
        }

        @Transformer(inputChannel="fromTcp", outputChannel="toEcho")
        public String convert(byte[] bytes) {
            return new String(bytes);
        }

        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="toEcho")
        public String upCase(String in) {
            return in.toUpperCase();
        }

        @Bean
        public TcpInboundGateway tcpInGate(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory)  {
            TcpInboundGateway inGate = new TcpInboundGateway();
            inGate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            inGate.setRequestChannel(fromTcp());
            return inGate;
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageChannel fromTcp() {
            return new DirectChannel();
        }
    }

}
```

---

Rabbit Config Class

```
package org.inc.imo.configuration;

@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {

    public final static String IMO_REQUEST_JEA = "imo.request.jea";

    public final static String IMO_REQUEST_INFO = "imo.request.info";

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
        admin.declareQueue(jeaRequestQueue());
        admin.declareQueue(infoRequestQueue());
        return admin;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue jeaRequestQueue() {
        return new Queue(IMO_REQUEST_JEA);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue infoRequestQueue() {
        return new Queue(IMO_REQUEST_INFO);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());

        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectWriter objectWriter() {
        return new ObjectMapper().writer();
    }

}
```

---

TCPConfig class

```
package org.inc.imo.configuration;

@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class TCPConfig {
    @Value("${imo.hostname}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${imo.port}")
    private int port;

    private static MessageChannel sendChannel;

    private static MessageChannel replyChannel;


    @Bean
    public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
        replyChannel = new DirectChannel();
        return replyChannel;
    }

    @Bean(name="sendChannel")
    public MessageChannel sendChannel() {
        MessageChannel directChannel = new DirectChannel();
        sendChannel = directChannel;
        return directChannel;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        connectionFactory.setSingleUse(false);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendChannel")
    public TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway() {
        TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        tcpOutboundGateway.setReplyChannel(this.replyChannel());
        tcpOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(true);

        return tcpOutboundGateway;
    }

}
```

---

TCPGateway Interface

```
package org.inc.imo.Domain;

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "sendChannel")
public interface TCPGateway {
    String send(String message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is like:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

And the suffered bean is like:

```
@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    admin.declareQueue(jeaRequestQueue());
    admin.declareQueue(infoRequestQueue());
    return admin;
}
```

So, you request here `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory` bean injection, but there is no one.

If you simply test against the local RabbitMQ, there is just enough to add one more bean:

```
@Bean
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new CachingConnectionFactory();
}
```

and your `AmqpAdmin` will be able to connect there.

Comment: That solved that issue but introduced another.  Now that I'm creating the factory method do I need to explicitly set the configuration parameters? I'm getting a connection refused exception from factory method amqAdmin. 
Caused by: BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amqpAdmin' defined in Configuration.RabbitConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [AmqpAdmin]: Factory method 'amqpAdmin' threw exception; nested exception is AmqpConnectException: ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Well, if it's not `localhost:5672` (default), then indeed you need to specify them into the `connectionFactory` definition.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  It was reading from my application.properties out of the box.  Is there a topic I should be reading about to get it to use my application.properties as opposed to doing it by hand via @Value?

Comment: Spring Boot: https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/. BTW, there are a ton of "Getting Started Guides": https://spring.io/guides

Comment: Those guides are really helpful in a lot of cases.  But what I'm trying to understand is how to get the connectionFactory created with the Properties automatically or close to it.  This was happening before I added the @Bean ConnectionFactory creator.  Unfortunately, it isn't anymore.

Comment: I found that I could atAutowired RabbitProperties and set parameters for the factory by hand.  This is much bettter then using atValue but not as good as having RabbitMQ do it itself.